# When ReactJs is appropriate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, frontend, dynamic-programming

From what I have been researching, ReactJS is the new craze in the world of front-end development. I can find few articles that are able to provide a bias free look on ReactJS. There is only praise for it, but should it be used everywhere? I know an html.erb file with javascript can accomplish what ReactJS can do. Everything has its place. Where does ReactJS and React Native fit in? Specifically when should they be used? I know JavaScript can handle a lot, but of those things it probably shouldn't handle, or there is a better solution.

I would greatly appreciate guidance on these questions.

Comment: Please see [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React has many cool features and is one of the best libraries for using for building UI apps

it utilizes something called the virtual dom to enhance performance in applications

it has a really intuitive pattern with storing state in local components which can be passed down to children components as `props`.

it integrates well with state management frameworks like Redux (there is a helper package called `react-redux` which makes the integration seamless) but it also has it's own context API which can be used for wider ranging state

it recently introduced the concept of hooks. these replaced lifecycle methods which were popular in previous versions and are now a cool way to "hook" into components and utilise functionality whilst the component mounts and unmount

of course, like with everything, there are alternatives. you can just use plain old vanilla which has it's own benefits or you can choose a popular alternative such as Vue.js.

There is no hard and fast rule specifically *when* it should be used. the ball is in your court

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and insight! Even if my question had no solid answer, your guidance helped me. I hope it may help others as well.